# how to set an ip address as the host header in IIS 7.5 bindings

Tags: iis-7.5

I am having an issue getting an IIS 7.5 website to answer when I connect to it using an IP address.

I have a Win2008 Server set up with IIS 7.5. It has only one IP address bound to it (10.10.10.10), and IIS listens on it just fine. I have IIS hosting two websites: defaultsite and mysite. Both of these two are necessary to be present. (To be fair, I have many more sites, but 2 will simplify things.)

Defaultsite is your typical IIS default site and has an IIS binding of "*:80:"

I want to access "mysite" via the DNS name but also the public IP address 1.1.1.1. So I've added the appropriate bindings: 
"*:80:1.1.1.1"
"*:80:mysite.com"

My DNS and load balancer are moving traffic just fine to the IIS server. Everything works fine when hitting the server via "mysite.com" and I get the defaultsite if I try other ways to get to the server.

The problem is when I use 1.1.1.1 to get to the server, I get there, but I'm still sent over to the "defaultsite" rather than "mysite." My IIS logs and the file contents I retrieve verify this behavior.

Any ideas on how to get an IP address set as the host header on a site binding? (Searching for this situation is vexing; since all my key terms are present any time you work with host headers/bindings.)

Comment: Do browsers send host headers when you try to access a site directly via IP?

Comment: They should. I've successfully done this setup before on IIS6. I'm just migrating this particular site with a strange configuration exception to IIS 7.5. The site works but for this one thing.

Comment: I just tried this on my server. I bound one of my sites to the IP with the same hostname as the IP then bound one of the other sites to the IP without the hostname, and despite there being no default site enabled (all my sites run with host headers), the second site stopped (I'm assuming because of a binding conflict). I'm running IIS7 on Win2k8 server (not R2) rather than 7.5 though. I don't know if this helps at all?

Comment: I think I am seeing the same behavior as you. My "default site" seems to move with the binding: *:80:10.10.10.10 and the binding *:80:1.1.1.1 never gets a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the binding for *.80 from the default site and make it respond to 10.10.10.10 and then your other site will get picked up when you type the 1.1.1.1 site.  IIS is responding to the request but the rule states 'If any site comes through on port 80, respond to the default site'.  The DNS name works because you are going by name and the lookup is not there on the default site.

Comment: I removed my *.80 binding on the default site and replaced with *:80:10.10.10.10. Behavior didn't change. I'm pretty sure IIS compares the host header against all defined host headers before it gets down to the wildcard one. Still, this got me thinking that maybe I'm hitting the defaultsite not because it's matching this rule so much as it's the first available site to send unknown traffic to...

Comment: I think this would work if 1.1.1.1 was also bound on the server as a second IP address. But 1.1.1.1 is a public address bound to my external firewall and NAT sends it internal to my load balancer and then to my IIS server.